General formula of elasticity of substitution
By definition, ES takes the form
$$
\sigma_{12} = \frac{d \ln (x_2/x_1)}{d \ln {MRTS_{12}}}
$$
Given some production function $F(x_1,x_2)$, I see a form that
$$
\sigma_{12} = -\frac{\frac{1}{x_1 F_1} + \frac{1}{x_2 F_2}}{\frac{F_{11}}{(F_1)^2} - \frac{2 F_{12}}{F_1 F_2} + \frac{F_{22}}{(F_2)^2}}
$$
where $F_1,F_2,F_{11},F_{12},F_{22}$ are the first and second order partial derivatives, respectively.
However, I don't know how to derive it. It would be great if some hints can be provided.
Thanks!

Dear Andy Xu pls. check if this post does not answer your question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/elasticity-of-substitution-of-crs-production-function. If it does we can close your question as a duplicate. If you think it does not pls. clarify why you think it does not.

Let's express everything in terms of $x_1$ First of all, the elasticity of substitution is determined keeping output fixed, so
$$
F(x_1, x_2) = C.
$$
For a constant $C$. This gives:
$$
F_1 + F_2 \frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = 0 \to \frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = -\frac{F_1}{F_2}.
$$
Next, consider the ratio:
$$
r = \frac{x_2}{x_1}.
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dr}{dx_1} &= \frac{1}{x_1} \frac{dx_2}{dx_1} - \frac{x_2}{(x_1)^2},\\
&= -\frac{1}{x_1}\frac{F_1}{F_2} - \frac{x_2}{(x_1)^2},\\
&= -\frac{x_2 F_1}{x_1}\left(\frac{1}{x_2 F_2}+ \frac{1}{x_1F_1}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Next,
$$
MRTS = - \frac{F_1}{F_2}.
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d MRTS}{dx_1} &= -\left(\frac{F_2\left(F_{11} + F_{12}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}\right) - F_1\left(F_{21} + F_{22}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}\right)}{(F_2)^2}\right),\\
&=\frac{-F_2 F_{11}+F_{12} F_1 + F_1 F_{21} - F_1 F_{22}\frac{F_1}{F_2} }{(F_2)^2},\\
&= -\frac{(F_1)^2}{(F_2)}\left(\frac{F_{11}}{(F_1)^2} -2 \frac{F_{12}}{F_1 F_2} + \frac{F_{22}}{(F_2)^2}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dr}{dMRTS} &= \left.\left(\frac{dr}{dx_1}\right)\middle/\left(\frac{dMRTS}{dx_1}\right)\right.\\
&= -\frac{\frac{1}{x_2 F_2} + \frac{1}{x_1 F_1}}{\frac{F_{11}}{(F_1)^2} - 2 \frac{F_{12}}{F_1 F_2} + \frac{F_{22}}{(F_2)^2}}\left(-\frac{F_2}{F_1}\frac{x_2}{x_1} \right)
\end{align*} 
$$
This gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d \ln(r)}{d \ln(MRTS)} &= \frac{d r}{d MRTS} \frac{MRTS}{r},\\
&= \frac{dr}{dMRTS} \left(-\frac{F_1}{F_2}\right) \frac{x_1}{x_2},\\
&=-\frac{\frac{1}{x_2 F_2} + \frac{1}{x_1 F_1}}{\frac{F_{11}}{(F_1)^2} - 2 \frac{F_{12}}{F_1 F_2} + \frac{F_{22}}{(F_2)^2}}
\end{align*}
$$
